# Access the Entity Framework model classes in API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, architecture

Project Architecture is like this:

- `MyProject.DataAccessLayer`: will communicate with database using Entity Framework
- `MyProject.BusinessLayer`: application business logic will be here
- `MyProject.API` : WebAPI `ApiControllers` will return the data from business layer methods

My question is that, if I have created an Entity Framework as separate project in the `DataAccessLayer`, how can I use the model classes from the `DataAccessLayer`?

Should I add a reference to `MyProject.API` to access the model classes? If this is the case, why would I need the `MyProject.BusinessLayer`?

**Edited**

Sample code for business layer:

```
  public async Task<List<TigerNest.Dao.Area>> GetArea()
          => await yatraDao.GetArea();
```

`ApiController`:

```
YatraManager manager = new YatraManager();
var result = await manager.GetArea();
return Ok(result);
```

In the `ApiController`, the `BusinessLayer` returns a collection of areas. It forces me to add reference to the `Dao` project.

Comment: The business layer has a reference to the DataAccesslayer, and the API has a reference to that business layer project. If you then need to access your DAL models from your API, you're not correctly using the business layer.

Comment: I have updated question with sample code

Comment: You don't have to update the code. It's exactly like @nbokmans said. API controller has a reference to the business layer, the business layer has a reference to the DA layer. `API (uses the )-> Business (uses the)-> DA Layer`.

Comment: But in api, I return as list of areas,  this area class available in da layer and it's entityframework generated class

Answer (score 1):

> If I have created Entity Framework as separate project in `DataAccessLayer`, how can I use the model classes from `DataAccessLayer` ?

You can put the model classes into an independent project `infrastructure`

> Should I add a reference to `MyProject.API` to access the model classes?

Yes, because you need to return data from API

> If this is the case why do I need `MyProject.BusinessLayer` ?

I suggest you might create a `Myproject.BusinessLayer`, because the business layer can place repetitive logic for later reuse.

We separate `UI`,`BusinessLayer`,`DataAccessLayer` those can reference with `infrastructure` project,`infrastructure` will use the  model, container ..

[image]

---

**Edit**

In brief, the UI layer is referenced to the BLL and the BLL is referenced to the DAO,and they all refer to the Infrastrure (DTO, ViewModel) common layer

In your question you might mapping `EF model` be `DTO model` on `BusinessLayer`,`ApiController` can use the `DTO model`.

So `ApiController` and `BusinessLayer` refer a new project `Infrastrure`,that put `DTO` or `ViewModel`,This way you can isolate the EF Model.

`DTO` (data transfer object) is like ViewModel but he exists in data conversion. `EF` Model corresponds to DB schema,`DTO` corresponds to `EF` Model.

`DTO` model should contain only data and not business logic.

I recommend a third party kit [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/),that helps us to map objects more easily.

---

**There are some article talk about AutoMapper and 3-Tier-Architecture**

[Easily Generate Data Transfer Objects from ADO.NET Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL Data Classes](https://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/dtogenerator-easily-generate-data-transfer-objects-from-ado-net-entity-framework-or-linq-to-sql-data-classes)

[Mapping Entity Framework Entities to DTOs with AutoMapper](https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-framework-and-wcf-mapping-entities-to-dtos-with-automapper/)

Comment: How can put the Model classes as separate project, since Entityframework generate the autocode from Db ?

Comment: You can create a `DTO` object  on  separate project.
Entityframework Db can mapping with it.

Comment: `DTO` (data transfer object) is like Model but he exists in data conversion.  
EF  Model  corresponds to  DB schema,`DTO`  corresponds to 
 EF Model

Comment: Can you refer any article which you are talking about?

Comment: @King_Fisher I put some article on answer, you could search key work "3-Tier EF"